# pg_dump export slows down as it progresses

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-migration, pg-dump

I am exporting table with **pg_dump**. Table has 150 GB
The source table is on Azure Managed Postgres DB, and I am running **pg_dump** on an AWS EC2 instance.
This is command that I am running:

```
pg_dump --blobs -Z0 -j 5 -Fd db_name -h db_host -U some_user -t mytable --schema=public --data-only -W -f dumpdir
```

The issue is that the first 6GB is exported in 3 minutes and each GB from 1 to 6 is exported really fast, then the export slows down. After 6GB it exports 100 MB in 5 minutes.

I am monitoring the AWS EC2 machine that is running pg_dump. Also, I am monitoring Azure DB and everything looks ok, from CPU, Memory, Network etc..

EC2 configuration:
32 CPU, 256 GB of RAM, Second Volume EBS (gp2) 3TB. The postgres version is 11.

Comment: how active is the source database?

Comment: We have running applications that constantly writing something to the source db. Maybe 100MB per day.

Comment: Sounds like one of your machine is throttled, and so slows down once it exhausts its grace period.

Comment: it does kind of sound like throttling, but the ec2 side looks pretty big to be subject to throttling.  Maybe the azure DB is being throttled

Comment: Thanks for advices. Right now I am not in front of my laptop, but will check that. Just not sure if it is able to check on Azure side because it is manages DB.

Comment: @erik258 jjanes I cant detect if it is related to Azure. CPU, Memory looks OK, but Network OUT is drastically increased and after some time drastically decreased (throttling). Also, I dont have any alter from Azure. 
One new thing, today I pass me to dump 25 GB and started throttling again.